# Clear Dependent Drop-Down List When the Parent List Changes

Tags: excel, vba, validation, drop-down-menu, range

In the example below, cell A10 contains a primary drop-down list (A10-E10 are merged cells to display the full length of each drop-down option).

When “We believe a check you deposited may not be paid for the following reason” is selected, a dependent drop-down appears in A12 that must also be selected from.

I’m trying to clear the contents of A12 when any other option is chosen in A10. A12-E12 are also merged cells, for the same reason.

[image]

I tried a few variations, but the basic code is below.

I get

> Run Time Error 1004 "We can't do that to a merged cell."

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("$A$10") <> "We believe a check you deposited may not be paid for the following reason:" Then
    Range("$A$12").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

Expecting to clear cell A12 when A10's selection does not equal "We believe a check you deposited may not be paid for the following reason:"

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the entire merged range.

Note that modifying the sheet will cause the change event to fire in an infinite loop as you currently have it. A standard approach is to disable events with `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Here, it's recommended first to test if `A10` was changed (using `Intersect`), which will also prevent the infinite loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Me.Range("A10"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If Me.Range("A10") <> "We believe a check you deposited may not be paid for the following reason:" Then
        Me.Range("A12:E12").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So here's a follow-up, using the same example.  Any time the spreadsheet is launched, I want to have cell A10 default to read "Please Select..."  I can't figure out the VBA to add that default text to A10.  I know I can restrict invalid entries using Data Validation, and I intend to do so, but I want to indicate up-front that cell A10 requires a selection.

Comment: You might research the `Workbook.Open` event, noting that changing the default text in A10 will clear A12:E12 per this answer unless you disable events.